# Error with the following dynamic sql statement

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am having an error I cannot see in the following dynamic SQL statement:

```
  SET @sql_statement =
    "INSERT INTO " +
      @archive_db_name + ".dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS 
    SELECT " +
      @reporting_db_name + ".dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS.* 
    FROM " +
      @reporting_db_name + ".dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS 
    WHERE " +
      @reporting_db_name + ".dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS.ORDER_ID 
    IN
      (
        select #tmp_table_order_ids.order_id
        from #tmp_table_order_ids
      )"
  EXEC(@sql_statement)
```

The error is:

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1:
Server 'server_name', Line 5:
Incorrect syntax near 'IN'`

But I cannot see any syntax errors at the location the error specifies. Could someone please kindly point out why I am getting this error?

Comment: I don't use Sybase, but does PRINT @sql_statement look okay?  Do you have SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the double quotes to single quotes

```
  SET @sql_statement = 
    'INSERT INTO ' + 
      @archive_db_name + '.dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS  
    SELECT ' + 
      @reporting_db_name + '.dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS1.*  
    FROM ' + 
      @reporting_db_name + '.dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS1  
    WHERE ' + 
      @reporting_db_name + '.dbo._TEST_TB_ACTIVE_ORDERS1.ORDER_ID  
    IN 
      ( 
        select #tmp_table_order_ids.order_id 
        from #tmp_table_order_ids 
      )'
  EXEC(@sql_statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error :

```
declare @reporting_db_name varchar(50)
declare @archive_db_name varchar(50)

declare @sql_statement varchar(500)

select @reporting_db_name ='PHILARIS_RD'

select @archive_db_name ='PHILARIS_RD'
SET @sql_statement =
    "INSERT INTO " +
      @archive_db_name + ".dbo.A 
    SELECT " +
      @reporting_db_name + ".dbo.A.* 
    FROM " +
      @reporting_db_name + ".dbo.A 
    WHERE " +
      @reporting_db_name + ".dbo.A.ID 
    IN
      (
        select B.ID
        from B
      )"
 EXEC(@sql_statement)
```